# Idiomatic way to implement context dependent MenuBar?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a `@FXML Menu editMenu` defined, and I want to populate it depending on which of my `TreeView`s is currently in focus, and on whether or not there are any `TreeItem`s selected.

What would be the idiomatic way of doing this? I haven't been able to find a nice `onFocus` method for the `TreeView`s.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Node`s have a [`focusedProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty) with which you can register a listener. Additionally, the `Scene` has a [`focusOwner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty) property you can observe.

So you can do something like

```
scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> obs, Node oldFocusOwner, Node newFocusOwner) {
        // update menu based on newFocusOwner
    }
});
```

If you're using FXML, it can be difficult to get hold of the `Scene` in the controller. You may need to do something like:

```
ChangeListener<Node> menuUpdater = new ChangeListener<Node>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> obs, Node oldFocusOwner, Node newFocusOwner) {
        // update menu based on newFocusOwner
    }
};

someNode.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> obs, Scene oldScene, Scene newScene) {
        if (oldScene != null) {
            oldScene.focusOwnerProperty().removeListener(menuUpdater);
        }
        if (newScene != null) {
            newScene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(menuUpdater);
        }
    }
});
```

where `someNode` is any node in the scene graph.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean the ``Scene`` object changes often? Simply adding the ``menuUpdater`` to the current ``Scene``'s ``focusProperty`` wouldn't work?

Comment: No, the `Scene` doesn't change often. But if you are using FXML, you are probably doing this in the controller's `initialize()` method, which is (obviously) called before the `Node`s defined in the FXML are added to the `Scene`. If you have direct access to the `Scene` in your code, then you can just use the first code sample.